# Glew not compiling in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, opengl, glew

I tried using the Glew Library for shading and was trying to compile a simple program using the NSOpenGLView Class in Xcode 5. The program fails at the following code in glew.h

```
#if defined(__gltypes_h_)
#error gltypes.h included before glew.h
#endif
```

It says that Gltypes.h is included before glew.h.

My implementation file for OpenGLView has headers included in following fashion:

```
#include <glew.h>
#import "OpenGLView.h" // Includes Cocoa.h
#include "LoadShaders.h" // Includes <OpenGL/gl.h>
```

So, if glew.h is included in the beginning, why is the error coming here. None of the other headers are included before the inclusion of glew.h, so tests for them(like gl.h) are passing in glew.h. I am not able to find out here as to who is including Gltypes.h in this file.

Hope anyone has a clue to it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precompiled header file (`.pch`) pulls Cocoa in. Edit it to include `glew.h` before `Cocoa.h` and you are good to go.